# Pwm counter without Microcontroller

Tags: pwm

I have a microcontroller that outputs pulses to a max of 250 kHz. 
Is there a capable ic that can count rising edges and interrupt on a set number of pulse?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how many pulses you are looking for. However, if the number of pulses is less than 10,  the 74HC4017 might suit your purpose.  The 4017 is a decade counter with 10 outputs.  Each output goes high on the appropriate count (low again after that count is exceeded).

Comment: Looking to count alot to drive a stepper but the .netmf microcontroller I'm using didn't expose anything without overhead would rather add in more hardware to handle it

Comment: The most appropriate 'more hardware' might be a small micro-controller.